# What is the relationship between a database and a CRUD?

Tags: reactjs, database, crud

I am trying to build a database to store information that I typed into the web, extracting it and using it at different points. I am creating something similar to a project-management tool on a website, like Monday.com. I have been looking at React CRUD and database to start storing and extracting data, however, I still do not understand the relationship between CRUD and a database. Am I even using the right tool? Can React create a database? What are some good frameworks for a simple database? I know Java, Javascript, HTML, CSS and Python. I understand the reluctance in giving answer to a fellow user, but please, if possible, point me in the right direction so I can at least search for something relevant that guide me in the right path.

Comment: CRUD are acronynims wich specify the 4 basics operation -> 
C: Create
R: Read
U: Update
D: Delete
It has nothing to do with react specificly, it could be a way to conceive your api and then you will consume it with a route to read / update / delete and create (post / put  / delete / get)

Comment: You basically need a database to save data, CRUD are the 4 basic operations which can be run on database. No, React can't directly connect to database. You need some kind of backend which will interact with database. And React will interact with this backend using some API generally a REST service. And this backend can be in javascript (express.js & Node) or Java or any other programming language.

Comment: People often speak about "CRUD application" when the app basically just edits static entries in a database and doesn't have any "application logic" (for example, your contact app on your phone is a classical CRUD application, as it only creates-reads-updates-deletes its entries based on user actions).

Comment: @Smile *React* can't, because it's a UI framework. Browsers, however, can--depends on the database. User-written back-end code is not a *requirement*, it's an *option*.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes correct, database can directly be accessed from browser but not a best practice. I should have mentioned this in my comment.

Comment: @Smile This doesn't make a lot of sense, but ok. There are swathes of apps that have zero need for anything other than a DB back end. That's what the Firebase DBs are, for example. I think your view of what constitutes a "database" is a little too narrow.

Comment: @DaveNewton Firebase DBs do involve REST APIs but yes user doesn't need to write them. Yes, agreed my view of database probably is a bit narrow as for me accessing database from browser meant directly opening a connection for eg. using `ActiveXObject`. Your points are fair.

Comment: @Smile How a database is accessed is an implementation detail.

Comment: @DaveNewton agreed

Answer (score 1):

CRUD basically means Create, Read, Update, Delete. These are all functions that one can in its most basic, perform on a database.

React is a front-end framework that can be used to input data from users that can be then be used to perform CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) on a database.

Some popular databases are MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres, etc. and they have to be installed and run separately and cannot run from a browser like HTML, CSS, Javascript.

To access databases from websites, you have to build some sort of API. What API does is basically communicate between the website and the database. Popular languages to develop APIs are Node, PHP, Python

Comment: Wow thank you for being so informative, I really do appreciate it. For a website that requires me to store data that users enter, is it suggested that I use a database? Is that very hard to learn and is it very tedious to create a simple database for the simple functionality of storing information that users input and extracting it when I need it?

Comment: If the data you want to save, is large or eventually will become large after use, then some type of database is the way to go. You can also save the data in some file like a text file.
But for either database or file saving, you will need to learn Serverside language like PHP, Node, etc.
For using database you will also need to learn that. Neither of these things is hard, just time taking and would be frustrating initially

Comment: I love you so much, THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad I could help. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

CRUD is a type of api (a standard way you should structure your server-side API) that defines a policy to access the database. As React is a front-end api, your react apps have a library to access those data using the CRUD standard. Depending on your application, you can use standard web hosting with AWS, or you can build your own server using node-js and express-js (express should have some kind of middleware to create a crud context for you database access)

Comment: Wow thank you for being so informative, I really do appreciate it. For a website that requires me to store data that users enter, is it suggested that I use a database? Is that very hard to learn and is it very tedious to create a simple database for the simple functionality of storing information that users input and extracting it when I need it?

Comment: Hi @leanNoCode, i got your idea, it ins't the definition. Look https://stackify.com/what-are-crud-operations/